# Saving dict generated by pandas read_excel to multi-sheet excel file

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas' [read_excel()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html?highlight=read_excel) method when called with `sheet_name=None` will return a dict with each excel sheet. How can I reverse this operation, i.e. take a dict and save a multi-sheet excel file? I'm only seeing a way to save a single dateframe to excel via the [to_excel()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that generally this operation is performed using `pandas.ExcelWriter` (suppose df_dict is your dictionary with DataFrames):

```
import pandas as pd
with pd.ExcelWriter('path/to/save/table.xlsx') as writer:
    for key, df in df_dict.items(): 
        df.to_excel(writer, key)
    writer.save()
```

[Documentation link](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_multiple.html)

Comment: Perfect! I tried to edit your answer, but the queue is full. Can you update your answer to be more general, i.e. instead of a string literal for `\`sheet_name\``, you could make a loop. `for key, df in df_dict: df_dict[key].to_excel(writer, key) writer.save()`  (sorry for poor code readability in a comment). That way this would represent the exact reverse procedure of `read_excel(sheet_name=None)`.

Comment: Hey @topher217, I’ve edited an answer with your suggestion, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you'll need to use a class called `ExcelWriter`, theres a cool example on their [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html):

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["AAA", "BBB"]], columns=["Spam", "Egg"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["ABC", "XYZ"]], columns=["Foo", "Bar"])
with ExcelWriter("path_to_file.xlsx") as writer:
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1")
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet2")
    writer.save()
```

Comment: Don't forget to call writer.save(), otherwise changes wouldn't be applied :)